# Why don't perpetual motion machines with superconducting magnets work?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, superconductivity, dissipation, perpetual-motion

A superconducting magnet works by energizing a superconducting magnetic coil, then short circuiting it to make a closed loop. Would it be possible to transfer the current back and forth between two superconducting magnets? This would allow perpetual motion, since you can move a magnet or a piece of metal back and forth in between the magnets. Obviously this can't work, but why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A perpetual motion machine that merely 100% conserves energy and thus operates forever like a perfect flywheel is of little interest and is not the same as as a perpetual motion where you can continually extract said energy from it ad infinitum for use.

In reality, however, there are always losses and in your example induced eddy currents in the metal and radio emissions from the superconductor are two them, even if you are content to watch it oscillate back and forth for all eternity without extracting the energy for work.

Answer (score 2):

When current changes in time, the medium is no longer exactly superconducting. There are energy losses, if not due to internal dissipation mechanisms, then due to EM radiation of the changing current.